# MongoDB querying array field with exclusion

Tags: mongodb

I searched around for a bit, but couldn't quite find the way to do this with MongoDB - or maybe I just misunderstand the $all and $in operators.

If I have the following documents:

```
{
  arr : ["foo","bar","baz"]
},
{
  arr : ["bar","foo"]
},
{
  arr : ["foo"]
}
```

I would like a query that returns the last two documents.  Basically any document that contains any combination of only `["foo", "bar"]` but excluding anything that has additional items.  It is the exclusion aspect that I can't figure out - basically for a given array, only return documents where the `arr` field contains only elements in that array.

```
> db.foo.find({arr : {"$in" : ["foo", "bar"]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a0ff6907560a1e88a2c0a"), "arr" : [  "foo",  "bar",  "baz" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a0ffc907560a1e88a2c0b"), "arr" : [  "foo",  "bar" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a0ffe907560a1e88a2c0c"), "arr" : [  "foo" ] }
> db.foo.find({arr : {"$all" : ["foo", "bar"]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a0ff6907560a1e88a2c0a"), "arr" : [  "foo",  "bar",  "baz" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a0ffc907560a1e88a2c0b"), "arr" : [  "foo",  "bar" ] }
>
```

Is this even possible?  I will not know what values are excludable at query time.

Comment: Can the values be repeated in the array?

Comment: Great question - no they can't be

Comment: Is the number of items in arr fixed?

Comment: No the number is not fixed

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by combining multiple operators:

```javascript
db.foo.find({arr: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['foo', 'bar']}}}})
```

The `$elemMatch` with the `$nin` is finding the docs where a single `arr` element is neither 'foo' nor 'bar', and then the parent `$not` inverts the match to return all the docs where that didn't match any elements.

However, this will also return docs where `arr` is either missing or has no elements.  To exclude those you need to `$and` in a qualifier that ensures `arr` has at least one element:

```javascript
db.foo.find({$and: [
    {arr: {$not: {$elemMatch: {$nin: ['foo', 'bar']}}}},
    {'arr.0': {$exists: true}}
]})
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, I've been searching for this the whole day. Take my +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to achieve what you want.  The query would be something like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$arr"}, 
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id", 
        // If arr is "foo" or "bar", add 0 to the sum else add 1 to the sum
        exclude:{$sum:{$cond:[{$or:[{$eq:["$arr","foo"]},{$eq:["$arr","bar"]}]},0,1]}}}}, 
    // Exclude all documents where "exclude" count is non-zero
    {$match:{exclude:0}}
])
```

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't used the framework.  It seems like it isn't possible w/ simple queries then - at least without using the $where with a function